# Is there anyway I can use PHPUnit on this Function?

Tags: phpunit

I want to use PHPUnit for this code but due to my lack of experience in the subject I got confused whether or not it is possible to use PHPUnit to test this code. Like for example I want to check whether the login was successful or not.
The function is called when a button is clicked.

function loginfunc(){

```
    var usernamev = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwordv = document.getElementById("password").value;


    $.ajax({
        url: "loginprocess.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {username:usernamev, password: passwordv}, // add a flag
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            window.location="loginprocess.php";
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error!')
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This is Javascript and PHPUnit is for testing PHP code. With PHPUnit you could test the loginprocess.php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As is mentioned in the comment by [gontrollez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1675789/gontrollez), PHPUnit tests PHP, not Javascript.